# CSS header doesn't go center

Tags: css

I'm trying to get navigation bar of height 40px on the top which I've now, Also I `position:fixed;` the only problem is, everything what I put inside the divs he showing up to the right and not at the center which I want, the navigation bar need to be 100%

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KxL6/)

this is my .css code:

```
.container{
        height:auto;
        margin-top:-10px;
        margin-left:-7px;
}
/*========================= TOP HEADER =========================*/
.banner{
        margin: 0pt auto;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#d9d8d6;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#000000;
        position:fixed;
        position: absolute;
}
.banner-container{
        height:40px;
        background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/WoVWvmy.png');
        background-size:40px 30px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:center;
        text-align:center;
}
```

These divs I use in index.php

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="banner-container">
            </div> <!-- END BANNER-CONTAINER -->
        </div> <!-- END BANNER -->
    </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;` after `position: fixed;` from `.banner`

Comment: Then go read a tutorial on CSS positioning, because center is not a valid value for the position property. Also remove the pt from the margin on banner. it should be margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restructured a little bit. Please see: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KxL6/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-container"></div>
    <!-- END BANNER-CONTAINER -->
</div>
<!-- END BANNER -->
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
/*========================= TOP HEADER =========================*/
 .banner {
    margin: 0pt auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d9d8d6;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your best bet.

Note I changed the HTML to use an `img` tag. It's easier to center these, and to manage them in general, than to do the same with CSS backgrounds:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WoVWvmy.png" class="banner-container" />
    </div> <!-- END BANNER -->
</div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

CSS:

```
.container{
        height:auto;
}
/*========================= TOP HEADER =========================*/
.banner{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#d9d8d6;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#000000;
        text-align: center;
}
```